# p.$key returning undefined in the url angular 8

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular8

**My html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

</html>

<p> <a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary">New Product</a> </p>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
      <td> {{p.title}} </td>
      <td> {{p.price}} </td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.$key]">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to retrieve products data one by one. But whenever i click on edit it return undefined in url.
Can someone please help me how to retrieve key in angualr from firebase. Like how would I retriev following key data.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the changes between two functions : snapshotChanges() and valueChanges(), former can provide Unique ID but later cannot. So try this ,

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
      <td> {{p.payload.val().title}} </td>
      <td> {{p.payload.val().price}} </td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.key]">Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And the typescript file associated should have a function like,

```
 getAll() {
    return this.db
      .list('/products').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

i.e. use snapshotChanges() instead of valueChanges() whenever you want to obtain keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the parent node, then you need to use the property `key` without `$`. Therefore do the following:

```
"['/admin/products/', p.key]"
```

Comment: I've changed it to "p.key" but still returning undefined.

Comment: Wat does product$ contain and what is its type

Comment: Are you getting p.title? If yes then just send `p` to the next page and then in typescript catch it and log it and check if you get the `key`

Comment: product$  is an observable